# Pass ion-select-option to function - Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have this `Ionic` version 4 code that is simply trying to take a the selected value and pass it to a function in it's component:

```
<ion-item>
<ion-label>Convert Currency</ion-label>
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="currency">
<ion-select-option *ngFor="let c of currencyData" [value] = "c" >{{c.text}}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

I tried `onChange` but that is apparently not in version 4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for **ionChange**

```
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="currency" (ionChange)="yourFunction($event)">
```

Comment: `ionChange` does successfully trigger. Do you know how to pass the selected value into the function?

Comment: just pass currency

Answer (score 8):

you can use ionChange to pass the selected value as follow :

```
     <ion-select (ionChange)="checkValue($event)"  interface="popover" 
      placeholder="Select One" >
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let c of currencyData" [value]="c"> 
       {{c.text}}</ion-select-option>
 </ion-select>
```

In your typeScript:

```
checkValue(event){ console.log(event.detail.value)}
```