# How can I get one doc from a collection, with ion-select listing all the docs?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I'm denormalizating data from some database, to avoid join querys, so when I'm going to register something in 'Pedido' collection, I put the data of the 'Usuario' (which is logged in), and the data of the selected 'Cliente'. I will display the entire 'Cliente' collection in an ion-select, so I can choose it and proceed, but how can I get the only selected doc from it? Also, as an bonus error, I can only select the first value of the 'Cliente' collection, the ion-select won't let me choose another.

```
      private formCriarPedido: FormGroup;
      private clientesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Cliente>;
      private clientes$: Observable<Cliente[]>;

      constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        public auth: AuthService,
        private toast: ToastService,
        private db: AngularFirestore
      ) {

        this.formCriarPedido = this.fb.group({
          clientePedido: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        });

        this.clientesCollection = this.db.collection<Cliente>('cliente');
        this.clientes$ = this.clientesCollection.valueChanges();
      }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

      iniciarPedido() {

      }

      escolheCliente(cliente: Cliente) {

        console.log(cliente);

      }
```

```
          <ion-label position="stacked">Cliente</ion-label>

          <ion-select class="selectCliente" (ionChange)="escolheCliente($event)" formControlName="clientePedido">

            <ion-select-option value="{{cliente}}" *ngFor="let cliente of clientes$ | async">{{cliente.razaoSocialCliente}}</ion-select-option>

          </ion-select>

          <div align-self-start ngxErrors="clientePedido">

            <div [ngxError]="['required']" [when]="['touched']">

              <p class="alert-validation">
                É necessário selecionar o Cliente! 
              </p>

            </div>

          </div>

        </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quickly found the mistake, as it seems, it's an ionic 4 change. To make this work in order, you should change this line:

```
        <ion-select-option value="{{cliente}}" *ngFor="let cliente of clientes$ | async">{{cliente.razaoSocialCliente}}</ion-select-option>
```

to:

```
        <ion-select-option [value]="cliente" *ngFor="let cliente of clientes$ | async">{{cliente.razaoSocialCliente}}</ion-select-option>
```

Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/users/11216133/othmane-daanouni at [Pass ion-select-option to function - Ionic 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53551889/pass-ion-select-option-to-function-ionic-4)